# What kind of projection does a specific map (3D -> 2D) correspond to?

Tags: coordinate-systems, projective-geometry, conformal-geometry, projection, scalar-fields

Suppose I have a 3D scattered data

$$(A_1,B_1,Z_1)$$$$(A_2,B_3,Z_3)$$$$(A_3,B_3,Z_3)$$$$...$$$$(A_n,B_n,Z_n),$$ shown schematically in the picture below and there is no order in the data.
[image]
Now, I build a map from 3D space to 2D space by subtracting the second coordinates from the first coordinates, in the following way:
$$(A_1,B_1,Z_1)\rightarrow(A_1-B_1,Z_1)$$$$(A_2,B_3,Z_3)\rightarrow(A_2-B_2,Z_2)$$$$(A_3,B_3,Z_3)\rightarrow(A_3-B_3,Z_3)$$$$...$$$$(A_n,B_n,Z_n)\rightarrow(A_n-B_n,Z_n)$$
So now I have a 2D scattered data and the plot looks like this: 
[image]
What does this map represent mathematically? What operation does it correspond to? It looks very much like some kind of projection... In which case what kind of projection is that? Onto a plane, or onto a curved surface? Orthogonal or non-orthogonal? How can I insert 2D plane with coordinates ($A-B,Z$) in the initial 3D space with coordinates $(A,B,Z)$? If these are the family of surfaces onto which a projection takes place, then one surface would be enough to show in the 3D space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors that lie in the A-Z plane are unmoved by this transformation.
A vector in the direction of B-axis is sent to a vector in the A-axis
of the same magnitude but opposite direction (ie change of sign).

Contrary to what gimusi says, it can also be regarded as projection, if you embed the image plane in 3d-space differently as below:
That is interpreting your map as $(A,B,Z)\mapsto (A-B, 0, Z)$, it would be a non-orthogonal projection, of course.

Comment: Your one is a very good point, I didn't considered this possibility but please revise the point on my answer since, to be precise, I've not affirmed that "it can't be regarded as projection" at all but that the matrix N I've considered is not a projection.

Comment: Viewed in this way it’s in fact an oblique projection parallel to $(1,1,0)$ onto the $x$-$z$ plane.

Comment: @amd, does it mean that it is a kind of shear mapping? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Overview

Comment: Not a shear. Think of rain drops falling on ground at angle. Same way this is projection to a plane moving in an angle (not perpendicular) to that plane. SHear is non-singular whereas this is singular (ie crushes a 3d-body to a 2d-figure)

Comment: @PVanchinathan, can it be regarded as non-orthogonal oblique projection?

Answer (score 0):

The transformation $\mathbb{R^3}\to \mathbb{R^2}$ corresponds to the multiplication by the matrix

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

We can also view it as a transformation $\mathbb{R^3}\to \mathbb{R^3}$ by the [matrix](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1,-1,0%7D,%7B0,0,1%7D,%7B0,0,0%7D%7D)

$$N=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

which is not  a projection, indeed $N^2\neq N$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! What would be the proper mathematical term for this transformation (more specific term than just multiplication by a matrix)? I reckon there is a way to show a surface in the 3D space, and the surface would have local coordinates $(A-B,Z)$. How could I do it?

Comment: @CapoPavelMestre It is not an invertible transformation, you can extract some information by eigenvalues and eigenvectors http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1,-1,0%7D,%7B0,0,1%7D,%7B0,0,0%7D%7D

Comment: Eigenvectors essentially form basis vectors, and a projection plane is a span of these vectors, right?

Comment: @CapoPavelMestre Note that the map interpreted as $(A,B,Z)\mapsto (A-B, Z, 0)$ is represented by the matrix N and it is not a projection and doesn't have  acomplete basis of eigenvectors, while interpreted as $(A,B,Z)\mapsto (A-B, 0, Z)$ it is a projection and the matrix associated has a complete bais of eigenvectors http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1,-1,0%7D,%7B0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,1%7D%7D

Comment: Thanks, @gimusi! So, it is up to me to choose the interpretation, either $(A,B,Z)\rightarrow(A−B,0,Z)$ or this $(A,B,Z)\rightarrow(0,A−B,Z)$. Both cases correspond to projections. And in general there is a family of projection planes, since we can choose any number instead 0, i.e. $(A,B,Z)\rightarrow(A−B,const,Z)$ or this $(A,B,Z)\rightarrow(const,A−B,Z)$, am I correct? In addition, having one of the eigenvectors with two non-zero elements means that it is a kind of shear mapping, yes? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Overview

Comment: @CapoPavelMestre the example of shear mapping is an (invertible) affine transformation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation while the projection here is not,  the interpretation on eigenvectors with eigenvalues $\neq0$ is simple (they represent the direction not modified by the transformation) but  I'can't say how to classify in general